# Inheritance in classes in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

So the Player class inherits traits from the Entity class but also has unique
traits of its own which are initialized within the Player class.

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, des):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.des = des
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, mana):
        self.mana = mana
```

Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: Generally, you need to call the super-class constructor in the subclass constructor, using `super().__init__` which is preferable to `Entity.__init__`

Answer (score 5):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, you probably want to call the super-class constructor. The way the `__init__` functions work, there is currently no way to pass arguments down through the constructors.

An alternative approach would be:

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, des):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.des = des

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, mana, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.mana = mana
```

That way, when the `Player` is created you can pass all the arguments in:

```
mana = 100
name = "bob"
health = 1000
des = "potato"
player = Player(mana, name, health, des)
```

It does have the odd pattern that new arguments are added to the start.

An alternative is to just use keyword arguments (having the `*` by itself means any non-keyword arguments will just get swallowed)

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, *, name, health, des):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.des = des

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, *, mana, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mana = mana
```

Then the player can be initialised with:

```
mana = 100
name = "bob"
health = 1000
des = "potato"
player = Player(mana=mana, name=name, health=health, des=des)
```

Comment: @MilesKent if this answer solved your problem, mark it wih the green check mark. It will mark it as solved and it is a nice way to thank the author of the answer for his/her time. My suggestion is to stick to the keyword argument version.